# Excel Help formula needed - multiple criteria over many ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]**Excel based question Help needed**

Struggling with a formula to return a value based on a number of criteria.

Lookup value = Nike or adidas, New balance (Column B) and value X (Column C) = 9 (unknown at time of entry)
return a value from Column D,  if the value in Column C is in range between a MIN of 1 (Column A) and max of 10 (Column B)

The only problem is that I have approx 38 ranges to search for for value x as this can be unknown over 38 rows in the spreadsheet.

Example of ranges

1-10
11-20
21-30 etc

I have tried index, match, loads of if(and( statements but this can only take up to 64 statements

Comment: Please put some example data and desired output in your question. It's very difficult to decypher as it is right now.

Comment: Min  Max   Nike     Adidas  Type Value
1 10   100      50  Nike          9
11 20   200      150   
21 30   300      200                                                                                                                        have to look up the type and the value and return the value in nike based on the value of 9, over the multiple ranges of min & max, in each row

Comment: have to return the value of Nike or adidas, in a different column to be a multiplier for a separate calculation

Comment: so u input Nike n get 9.. or u input 9 and get Nike?